# Where to place application logic in new Activity code generated by ADT 22.6.2

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

In the latest versions of eclipse (ADT v22.6.2) the create android application now generates an activity_main.xml and a fragment_main.xml. It generates only a single activity class
but this now has an embedded inner static fragment class  that is created by the activity in its onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new       PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

....
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
```

My confusion is how to port old code/examples where there was only 1 activity and the main application
logic is usually put in the Activity onCreate method i.e. stuff like findViewById. Listeners 
etc

The way I have approached it is that I put all my user created views as members of the static PlaceHolderFragment class. Then I call this in the fragment onCreateView. I still have some logic in the activity and it stores a pointer to the fragment. It updates the views members by calling getters on the fragment. Is this correct or should all logic be moved to the fragment now ?
All the tutorials/examples use the old approach where logic is placed in the activity
so there is no reference documentation for how to use the new files that Eclipse generates for an Android application. Any help appreciated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the files that Eclipse generate automatically: You can do whatever that you want!!!

Fragment is a element between an Activity and a container.That's mean that you can put the logic of your code inside of one fragment with not problems.

In theory, fragments are used when you want to manage screens using different modules, containers. It's a fragment, a module, part of one screen (but also can be used in a full screen looking as an activity and with the same behaviour than one activity.) For example, imagine that you have for mobile phone screens, one list of news in one screen, and when you click, your app go to the next screen for show the content of the news, right? Ok, so you can use for these 2 screens: 2 activities for each one or one parent activity with 2 fragments...whatever that you want...

Imagine the same case, for a tablet version of your app, now the left part of the screen you should show the list of news and in the right part of the screen, the contain of each news clicked, right?   In that case, would be completly necessary to use one activity parent with two fragments...in that case, we could reuse almost the same case for the mobile phones or tablet.

And now, focus in your question:  if you don't want complicate the life (not too much, because work with fragment is easy too) I will recomend you to use only activities for your app.

But, like your question, you want to port, there isn't any problem. Now imagine that your activity is going to be only the class where you are going to manage the fragments. The logic for each screen has to be in each fragment. Use the activity only for replace fragments, or share information between fragments, etc. The activity will be like the orchestra director.

From each fragment, you can access to methods or public variables of your activity using  ((NameOfActivity)getActivity()).

Is it clear for you?

One more stuff, in fragment, normally the method that we used for initialize stuffs is onCreateView  (and not onCreate like activities).

Comment: Thank Juan Pedro so you are saying for simple cases you can delete what Eclipse gives you and just use activities as normal. In cases where you need fragments place the screen logic in the fragment and just use the activity for replacing and sharing information between the different fragments. Very well explained I will have to study fragments in detail to fully understand there power. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, it is...create an application with fragments, maybe is a little bit more complex than with only activities but at the end, is easier reuse code (screens) when you want to adapt your app also for tablets (also there are others advantages). And yes, you can continuous working only with activities, delete the activity and fragment the eclipse created for you and create your activities from scratch...make sure that you include them in your AndroidManifest.xml.  If it was helpfull, please vote my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Juan Pedro. I currently don't have high enough reputation to vote. But when I do I will be sure to vote for your excellent answer. I'm working on increasing my reputation